# How to Convert Unknown string format to time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

6   1 I am new to Pandas and Python. I want to do some date time operations in my script. I am getting date time information from a csv file in following format: PT12M20S

How to convert it into pandas datetime format? Something like: 12:20

During Convertion Error is : Unknown string format: PT13M20S

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us your code u have tried to solve it by

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.to_datetime("PT12M20S", format='PT%HM%MS')
```

Replace the single string "PT12M20S" with your dataframe column.

EDIT: to reflect additional information given in the comments:

You can use errors="coerce" to ignore all cases where the first format cant be used. And then fill all the missing values using their respective format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["PT20M23S", "PT45M", "PT25S"], columns=["date"])

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="PT%HM%MS", errors="coerce"). \
    fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="PT%MM", errors="coerce")). \
    fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="PT%SS", errors="coerce"))
```

output:

```
                 date
0 1900-01-01 20:23:00
1 1900-01-01 00:45:00
2 1900-01-01 00:00:25
```

Alternatively you can design your own function and apply it.

```
from datetime import datetime
def format_date(val):
    for f in {"PT%HM%MS", "PT%MM", "PT%SS"}:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(val, f)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return None

df["date"].apply(lambda x: format_date(x))
```

Comment: time data 'PT49S' does not match format 'PT%HM%MS' (match)

Comment: So how many different formats do you have in your data?

Comment: PT49S is not the same format as PT12M20S

Comment: PT20M23S,PT45M,PT25S are the format in data